# Calculate time (in hours and minutes) from given rate of payment (in VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can I generate the time (in hours and minutes) from given rate (for payments)? The user will need to enter the payment and the rate to get the total time duration. How can this mission be accomplished?

**example:**

```
rate = $2.00 per hours
payment = $5.00
```

result:

```
duration = 02 h 30 minutes
```

Thank you.

Comment: you divide the payment by the rate and that gives you the number of hours.. (ie. 5/2 = 2.5)

Comment: hello. I tried to do that. But I'm stuck with minutes. Maybe my head is a bit cracked now in the midnight

Comment: I couldn't understand the situation. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: see the examples for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TimeSpan` to simplify your code...

```
Private Function GetDuration(hourlyRate as decimal, payment as decimal) As TimeSpan
    return TimeSpan.FromHours(payment / hourlyRate)
End Function

' ...

Dim duration = GetDuration(2, 5)
Console.WriteLine("{0} hours {1} minutes", duration.Hours, duration.Minutes)
```

**Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/2tvYMK**

Comment: +1 for the advice for using timespan. thumbs up for the advice for using function to accomplish my mission. and another thumbs up for providing a fiddle. **mega thanks**

Answer (score 1):

```
hours = payment \ rate;
minutes = (payment/rate - hours) * 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the decimal point representation of time in hours (ie. 2.5), all you have to do is:

1. take the integer part - that's the number of full hours;
2. subtract the integer part from total and multiply by 60; that's the number of minutes

Something along these lines should work:

```
Dim hours as Integer
Dim minutes as Integer

Dim time as Double

time = payment / rate

hours = CInt(time)
minutes = CInt((time - hours) * 60)

Console.WriteLine("duration = {0} h {1} minutes", hours, minutes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TimeSpan` structure. It will do the calculations of hours and minutes for you.

```
Dim rate As Double = 2.0
Dim payment As Double = 5.0
Dim time = TimeSpan.FromHours(payment / rate)
Dim duration = [String].Format("{0:00} h {1:00} minutes", time.Hours, time.Minutes)
' ==> "02 h 30 minutes"
```

You can also use the `Decimal` type when working with money. It has the advantage of not introducing additional rounding errors when converting from and to binary formats. However, `TimeSpan.FromHours` expects the hours as `Double`. Therefore `Double` seems appropriate for this little example.